How to create multiple sessions/tabs?
We are working on a CTI application where we handle the calls and chat, we are using Open CTI JS APIs for the integration. For every call/chat we have to do a screen pop for the matched record in the CRM against the customer number. At the end of call/chat, we do create an activity for that interaction (chat/call).
We are able to develop this functionality when we have one interaction in our system (one call or chat), but we need to support multiple interactions simultaneously. The problem that we face when there are multiple interactions simultaneously in the system the screen pop for the latest interaction replaces the screen pop for previous interaction, this also disturb our activity creation process as well.
Therefore, we would like to know that if we can create multiple sessions or tabs dynamically in the salesforce, so that we can create separate session for each customer interaction?
Looking forward to your help on this,
Thank you.
